How does Chani know Paul hasn't had a nightmare in a while?
Chani comforts Paul, who has just woken up from a nightmare:

Chani: I'm here, I'm here. It's been a while since you've
had one of those nightmares.

How does Chani know Paul hasn't had a nightmare in a while?

They sleep every night together and she pays attention. What sort of answer are you expecting here?

@JiminyCricket this user went through a similar flurry of very literal questions about Spiderverse. It's not an English language barrier thing, because they seem fluent in English. I won't say what I think is going on because it'll spark a discussion, and in any case, no big deal: I downvote and move on. Valorum seems to have taken the noble cause of patiently answering all of their questions, no matter how obvious the answer, anyway.

I understand. So many demands for our attention now, it's easy to miss a pattern @AndresF.

Like most people, Paul tosses and turns when he has nightmares. Chani sleeps in the same bed as Paul and would likely be aware of when he's having a nightmare because he would disturb her sleep also.

Duncan did not make the mistake of assuming that the danger was past.
Now, on his security rounds, he paced the halls, sword in hand, eyes
alert. He opened Paul’s door to make sure that nothing threatened the
Duke’s son. The boy slept soundly in his room, though his bed-sheets
were a tangle — evidence that he had been tossing and turning, as he
often did when he had one of his vivid nightmares. In an adjacent bed
his guest, Bronso Vernius, snored softly. Prince Rhombur had insisted
that the two boys room together and watch out for each other.
Paul of Dune

The subtext here is that a time jump has occurred in the narrative of the film. They use the fact that Chani is aware of Paul's sleeping patterns to indicate, to the audience, that they've been sleeping together for quite some time and hence that we're now 'a few months later...'

Note that disturbed sleep, as a result of prophetic visions, appears to be a common feature to the Atreides men. His son does it too.

“No-o-o.” Ghanima shook her head. “But he has this odd empathy for
her. And … in his sleep, he often mutters Jacurutu.”
“That again!” And Jessica found herself recounting Gurney’s report
about the conspirators exposed at the landing field.
Children of Dune

